# Nullable<DateTime> always null in WCF service?

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

I have a WCF contract that has 3 `DateTime?` parameters in it. On my page, I'm using jquery to pass a javascript object with those 3 dates in it. When the javascript is NOT null, the service still receives it as null. They do need to be Nullable sometimes, so I can't just remove that.

C#:

```
public class Search {
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int? OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

JS:

```
var search = {};
search.FirstName = $('#SearchFirst').val() || null;
search.LastName = $('#SearchLast').val() || null;
search.DateOfBirth = $('#SearchDOB').val() || null;
search.From = after;
search.To = before;
search.OrderID = null;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: search,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#SearchLoading').hide();
        DisplaySearchResults(data);
    },
    type: "Post"
});
```

I'm using some test values such as `new Date('10/14/2013')` for `before` and `new Date('10/15/2013')` for `after`.

Fiddler reports that the POST body looks like this:

> FirstName=&LastName=&DateOfBirth=&From=Mon+Oct+14+00%3A00%3A00+MDT+2013&To=Tue+Oct+15+00%3A00%3A00+MDT+2013

Other fields such as `FirstName` and `LastName` are coming through properly. For now, OrderID will always be null but the dates are all coming in as null with no warnings or errors. What can I do?

Comment: I see you do not have the `contentType: 'application/json;',` on your AJAX call; could that be the issue?

Comment: @rae1 If he has decorated his OperationContract with the proper RequestFormat attribute, then he shouldn't need to explicitly set it. I think this might have to do with the format of the date not being acceptable by the DateTime conversion.

Comment: @crush It only needs to be a date, not a full fledged datetime. How should I construct a string for the service to pick up as a date with no time?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I tried finding out what all acceptable formats can be automatically converted by the JSON DataContractSerializer, but I haven't found anything yet. I know that DateTime.parse expects a string in MM/DD/YYYY, but it might also support other formats; furthermore, I'm not even sure it's used in the JSON serialization. I'll just defer to someone with more intimate knowledge of the serialization process.

Comment: You could also try using the toUTCString() method when passing the dates. E.g.: search.From = start.toUTCString()

Comment: Because I only needed the dates, I decided to pass `10/14/2013` instead of a full date. This converted properly. I don't want to answer my own question with such a half ass answer though... Somebody may need to transfer the time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like formatting issue.. Can you possibly use `Date.prototype.toISOString()` function before sending it up to the server?

Here's a [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) and in case you want to make it work on >IE9 browsers, you can [extend it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) as per example.

You can also configure [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see more details about the request

```
<messageLogging 
       logEntireMessage="true" 
       logMalformedMessages="true" 
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
```

-D